# jQuery delegate for TR, ignoring links

Tags: jquery

I use event delegation to display ,on click,a popup with detailed info on each TR of a table.
However, the TR has some actual links, and I need to avoid showing the popup if a link is being clicked. (so show the popups only when the user clicks on a portion of the TR that is not a link.
can anyone point me into the right direction?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cancel propagation on all links in the table:

```
$('table').delegate('td', 'click', function (e) {
    // do some code
});

$('table').delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();           
});
```

EDIT:
in a single delegate, somthing like this (not tested!):

```
$('table').delegate('td', 'click', function (e) {            
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
        e.stopPropagation();           
    }
    // do some code                       
});
```

Comment: thanks, Shlomi. I thought about this, but I hoped there's a way to achieve this in a single "delegate"

Comment: i added in a single delegate, try it

Comment: e.target.nodeName was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use method chaining to reduce the code, but the credit is all goes to @Shlomi Komemi

```
$('table').delegate('td', 'click', function (e) {
    // do some code
}).delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();           
});
```